# An alternative definition of a ($C^r$) manifold [Hirsch, Differential Topology, Chapter 1, Exercise 8]

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

To paraphrase the exercise:

> An atlas of class $C^r$ is sometimes defined as a collection of
>   bijective maps from subsets of $X$ to open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$
>   such that all coordinate changes are $C^r$. Given such an atlas
>   $\Phi=(\phi_i,U_i)_I$, show that there exists a unique topology on $X$ making $\Phi$
>   a $C^r$ atlas on $X$.

I think that I properly solved this exercise by constructing the minimal topology on $X$ that renders all $\phi_i$ continuous on their given open domains and further showing that this is also the maximal topology for which the charts are bi-continuous.

> My question: Is the family $$\left(\phi_i^{-1}(O_i)_{O_i \text{ is open in } \phi_i(U_i)} \right)_{i \in I}$$ a basis for the topology on  $X$?

It is clear that every point in $X$ is included in some member of the family but I seem to fail to (explicitly/constructively) prove that for any intersection of two members of a family, there is another member that is included in the intersection.

Remark: Hirsch does not assume any separability or countability axiom for a manifold $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the collection $$\{ \phi_i^{-1}(O) \mid i \in I, O \subset \Bbb R^n \text { is open}\}$$

Suppose $x \in \phi_i^{-1}(O_i) \cap \phi_j^{-1}(O_j)$. Then there is an open neighborhood $N$ of $\phi_i(x)$ such that $\phi_j\circ\phi_i^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism of $N$ to a neighborhood of $\phi_j(x)$.

Let $\tilde N = N \cap O_1 \cap \phi_i \circ \phi_j^{-1}(O_2)$. As the intersection of three open sets $\tilde N$ is open. And $x \in \phi_i^{-1}(\tilde N) \subset \phi_i^{-1}(O_i) \cap \phi_j^{-1}(O_j)$

Comment: Should I implicitly conclude that $\phi_i \phi_j^{-1}:  \phi_j (U_i \cap U_j) \to \phi_i ( U_i \cap U_j)$ is a map between open sets from the fact that it is defined to be $C^r$?

Comment: That is not implicit, but quite explicit. The definition of $\Phi$ being $C^r$ is exactly that every such map $\phi_i\phi_j^{-1}$ is $C^r$, and therefore continuous. Note that by exchanging $i$ and $j$, this includes the inverse map, so they are homeomorphisms.